# routing in nodeJs - What could be the reason my routing is not working?

Tags: node.js, express

I managed my routing via a few routers, but something went wrong,
when i try to call a functton i get the error:

Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
I can't understand what could be my problem..
I would be greatfull if soembody can help

my code:

```
// index.js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const userRouter = require("./userRouter");
const qeustionRouter = require("./questionRouter");
const questionToTestRouter = require("./questionToTestRouter");
const testRouter = require("./testRouter");
const subjectRouter = require("./subjectRouter");



/* GET home page. */
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
res.render("index", { title: "Express is run" });
});

router.get("/user",userRouter);
router.get("/qeustion",qeustionRouter);
router.get("/questionToTest",questionToTestRouter);
router.get("/test",testRouter);
router.get("/subject",subjectRouter);


module.exports = router;
```

another router for example:

```
// userRouter.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');



router.post('/signUp', userController.signUp)
router.get('/login', userController.login)
router.delete('/deleteStudent', userController.deleteStudent)
router.delete('/deleteTeacher', userController.deleteTeacher)
router.get('/getAllUsers', userController.getAllUsers)
router.get('/getStudentsByTeacherId/:teacherId', userController.getStudentsByTeacherId)
router.get('/getTeachersByStudentId/:userId', userController.getTeachersByStudentId)
router.post('/updateUser', userController.updateUser)


module.exports = router
```

```
// app.js
var express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors")
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//var path = require("path");
// var favicon = require("serve-favicon");
// var logger = require("morgan");
// var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var routes = require("./routes/index");

var app = express();

// view engine setup
// app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
// app.set("view engine", "jade");

// // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
// // app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
// app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// app.use(cookieParser());
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(cors());
app.use("/", routes);


//--------------------------------------
//listen to localhost
app.listen(4000, (req, res) => {
  console.log("listening on port 4000");
})
//--------------------------------------

//connect to mongo//
const connectionParams = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  // useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT, connectionParams)
  .then(() =>
    console.log("connected to mongo"))
  .catch((error) =>
    console.log("error: " + error))



// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error("Not Found");
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get("env") === "development") {
  app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render("error", {
      message: err.message,
      error: err,
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error", {
    message: err.message,
    error: {},
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This comes probably from the `res.render` command that you use. Check the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render) whether you have configured a template engine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a view engine. I see you are defining "jade" as your view engine but it is commented out and it is not in the index.js

1. please make sure you installed jade package. You can check this by looking at your package.json file.

`npm install jade --save`

2. You need to define jade as your view engine (in the index.js) and your jade files must be stored inside the views folder. Inside index.js file, you can change all `router` keywords to `app`

```
const express = require ("express");
const app = express ();
app.set("view engine","jade")
```

And delete this: `const router = express.Router();`

3. And this folder must be placed at the root of your project (in other words, your index.js file and "views" folder should be at the same level). If you do it in this way, you wont need to define a path route.

I kindly advise you to use "ejs" as your view engine. It is more common than "jade". You can create ejs files easily, just like an html page.

And first start with a single route to test if your express framework is working. You can then gradually add up other routes. And please let me know if this answer helps, otherwise I will delete.

Comment: thank you very much!! i tried that out, when i try to define the view engine in the index.js i get the error: TypeError: router.set is not a function, i tried also to uncomment the definition of that in app.js, and then when i try to call a function i get the error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory. i must say that i actually don't have any views yet, maybe it changes the picture..

Comment: i do started with routing everything threw the index.js and it worked, but when i moved that to different router files things went wrong, 
if you have any other idea for me i would be thankfull

Comment: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory. - - This is error is because you have `"res.render("error",...)` at the end of your app.js file. If you don't have an `error` template inside views folder, then you need to delete this line.

Comment: `TypeError: router.set `----- I also checked for this error. You will need to change `router` keywords inside index.js to `app`. I will edit my answer, you can see the change in the second point.